# Mysterious metrics in GCP Compute Engine API when the account does not use GCP compute

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have GCP account which I am using only Datastore in Native mode (Firestore), and Firebase Hosting/Auth. In this account, I am seeing a lot of `compute` related metrics getting generated from my dashboard as shown below. I have 0 ec2 compute vm instances running & no Kubernetes cluster running in the account.

[image: metrics dashboard]

Is it common to have these metrics generated in GCP even when you are not using anything in `compute`? If I do not get charged for these requests, I am guess I can ignore them... but I am a bit concerned that these metrics can distract viewing meaningful metrics generated from actual APIs that I use.

I am adding some of the top invoked methods below.

```
compute.v1.InstancesService.List    42,539  0   0.235 seconds   0.519 seconds
compute.v1.ZonesService.List    28,571  0   0.286 seconds   0.521 seconds
compute.v1.ZoneOperationsService.List   21,513  0%  0.233 seconds   0.518 seconds
compute.v1.DisksService.List    21,010  0   0.236 seconds   0.518 seconds
compute.v1.HttpHealthChecksService.List 15,757  0   0.24 seconds    0.52 seconds
compute.v1.RegionForwardingRulesService.List    14,693  0   0.245 seconds   0.52 seconds
compute.v1.RegionBackendServicesService.List    7,350   0   0.244 seconds   0.52 seconds
compute.v1.TargetVpnGatewaysService.List    7,343   0   0.247 seconds   0.521 seconds
compute.v1.VpnTunnelsService.List   7,343   0   0.245 seconds   0.52 seconds
compute.v1.FirewallsService.List    7,052   0   0.272 seconds
compute.v1.RegionDisksService.List  6,887   0   0.243 seconds   0.52 seconds
compute.v1.BackendServicesService.List  708 0   0.148 seconds   0.261 seconds
compute.v1.GlobalForwardingRulesService.List    705 0   0.15 seconds    0.261 seconds
compute.v1.RegionOperationsService.Get  585 0   0.195 seconds   0.396 seconds
compute.beta.BackendServicesService.List    525 0   0.152 seconds
```

Comment: Are you merely charged for `firebase` and `firestore` because you have enabled the Compute Engine Api? Or are these in-view all allowed by firebase's zero-trust and so discounted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is normal. If you review the list, all APIs are the `list` or `get` type. This is Google Cloud's management software obtaining lists of what resources you have. In Google Cloud, APIs are tracked both for usage and for security reasons (who is accessing what and when).

Most Google Cloud Services fit into or use resources from the `Compute` family of services. This includes networking, firewalls, gateways and other necessary services.

Comment: This might be normal but it is not expected *and perhaps nor natural*. "[Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/cloud-run-story-serverless-containers) comes with a generous free tier and is pay per use, which means you only pay while a request is being handled on your container instance. **If it is idle with no traffic, then you don’t pay anything**," certainly is thus bad advice for idle ...references? Unless there is a use to cloud run without [node pools](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#id=6fb11c1c-1c30-4457-88ba-e2ff83308c00). `listReferrer`/s